# What is the double slash (//) directory?

Tags: filesystem

I mistakenly typed `cd //` instead of `cd /`. To my surprise, current directory showed up as `//`.

What is that directory? Why does it exist?

```
apple@snipped $ pwd
/home/apple
apple@snipped $ cd /
apple@snipped $ pwd
/
apple@snipped $ cd //
apple@snipped $ pwd
//
apple@snipped $ cd ///
apple@snipped $ pwd
/
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`//` is usually the same as `/`.  `///` must be the same as `/`.

`ls` would have shown you that `cd //` took you to the root directory, the same as `cd /` does.

```
$ cd /
$ ls
bin
boot
dev
...
$ cd //
$ ls
(same as above)
```

The technical way to confirm they are definitely the same directory is:

```
$ cd /
$ stat -c "%i" .
2
$ cd //
$ stat -c "%i" .
2
```

they will print the same inode number, meaning they are the same thing.

The gory details are documented in the [POSIX Pathname Resolution specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11):

> A pathname consisting of a single slash shall resolve to the root directory of the process. A null pathname shall not be successfully resolved. A pathname that begins with two successive slashes may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner, although more than two leading slashes shall be treated as a single slash.

Comment: Probably something POSIX left open for an equivalent to Windows UNC paths in case a UNIX wanted to do something like `\\hostname\...`, similar to how `file://hostname/...` is valid but implementation-defined.

Comment: Note that it is not limited to UNC-like meanings; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256497/on-what-systems-is-foo-bar-different-from-foo-bar