# Why can I cd to "//"?

Tags: command-line, filesystem

I recently made a typo in a `cd` command and found that I was not only able to `cd` to `/`, but also if I ran the command:

```
cd //
```

For instance (I could put stuff after it such as files and folders in the `/` directory and it would still show the same `//` as well as actually go to the right places), I would be able to actually go to `//` which is seemingly acting the same as `/` and this appears to be the only difference:

```
<username>@<computer-name>://$
```

Apart from `pwd` also showing the `//` in the output.

So why is there a `/` and a `//`? What is the difference? Is this a bug or is there some purpose for having both of them? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1 with GNOME 3.20.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690828/what-does-double-slash-in-cd-mean-in-linux

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/23808/what-is-the-double-slash-directory/23809#23809